# Server response to multiple asyncronous XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, web-applications, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a Web Application that makes multiple simultaneous XHR calls (using Ajax rather than native Javascript).

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Services/Service.asmx/MyFunction',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'something': 'Something'
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        // Do something with the returned data.
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
});
```

When I debug the application and make two or more calls at the same time, I can see that the XHR calls are made immediately (after page load) by the client but the waiting time associated with those calls to the same web method producing the same response gets progressively longer.

[image]

It's as if the server is handling each XHR call one after another rather than in parallel (ie receiving the requests, processing the first one, responding to it, processing next request, etc.).

Is this by design or is their a way to have the server act on each request independently and in parallel?

Comment: you've shown nothing of the server code, not even hinted at what language it's written in, yet it's probably the server code that is the source of the server taking time to respond ... also you say "progressively longer" - yet the image shows 2, 5, 4, 3, 6 seconds ... that's not progressively anything

Comment: That comes from your server.  This would usually happen if you enable session state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what your backend is and how it's configured. It could be a VPS, it could be a dedicated server, it could be a cloud. It could have one node or several nodes. It can use one database or the databases could be distributed.

Since you noticed that the requests aren't handled simultaneously, in your case it looks like the server had one node / one process / one database. Or maybe it's unable to run these two operations in parallel because the result of the second request depends on the result of the first one.

Comment: Excellent spotting.  It was completely in the back end and just as Krzysztof suggested had to do with node/process/database constraints.  The code for the web method (written in C#) was grabbing content from an AWS S3 bucket and drawing it back to the server for processing.  (There must be limits on how many simultaneous AWS S3 connections you can have.  Need to look into that because I'll be needing more than one.)  On a dummy web method (eg. Thread.Sleep(5000)), all of the requests get sent at the same time and come back at the same time.  Many thanks Krzysztof.

Comment: WAIT!  I spoke to soon. I did a bit more digging on AWS S3 and went back over my code.  It all looks good and the discussions on AWS S3 says there are no solid limits on connections.  What else could it be?  @SLaks got it.  The problem with my concurrent Ajax requests was the 'session state'.  I needed to decorate the class code with: `[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]` Go [here](http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/) for more details.